# ASP.NET MVC3/Razor C# two sides/interfaces web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am building ASP.NET MVC3/Razor C# and I need two sides/interface base web aplication, that means I need this:

Admin side, where I will add Clients, and Client side, when client can log in and manage something too. Urls should look like these:

www/Client/ClientId/Controller/Action/Id

www/Admin/Controller/Action/Id

And I want something like this: controllers which belongs to Admin have in direcotry Controllers/Admin, and controllers which belongs to client have in directory Controllers/Client. The same with Views: Views/Admin, Views/Client. Problem is when I have url www/Client/Project and www/Admin/Project, and both are taking the same controller, which is not what I want.

So please help me to solve this, design best structure. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can organise your site into separate sections using areas:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx

If they are completely separate then it's probably cleaner just to create them as separate MVC applications, with common code in a business layer. However using areas will let you link between the two sections easier (for example, if you wanted to display "edit" links next to data in the client section).

Comment: Another question. Where is the best place to test, if Client exists in my db? I mean if the given clientId in urls: Client/{ClientId} exists?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably just create a separate website for each of the Admin and Client sites.  It's much cleaner that way.  If you have any code you want to share between the projects just make a business layer dll that has the shared code you need.